# Run a gitlab pipeline based on a condition

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have to run a pipeline based on some conditional which I want to evaluate in `.gitlab-ci.yml` config. file. Basically, I want to create jobs based on if a condition is true. Below is my current `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

```yml
# This is a test to run multiple pipeline with sing .gitlab-ci.yml file.
# identifier stage will identify which pipeline (A or B) to run and only jobs
#  of that pipeline would be executed and rest would be skipped.

# variables:
    # PIPE_TYPE: "$(mkdir identifier; echo 'B' > identifier/type.txt; cat identifier/type.txt)"
    # PIPE_TYPE: "B"

stages:
    #- identify
    - build
    - test

#identify:
#    stage: identify
#    before_script:
#        - mkdir "identifier"
#        - echo "B" > identifier/type.txt
#    script:
#        - PIPE_TYPE=$(cat identifier/type.txt)
#        - echo $PIPE_TYPE
#    artifacts:
#        paths:
#            - identifier/type.txt

before_script:
    # - mkdir "identifier"
    # - echo "B" > identifier/type.txt
    # - export PIPE_TYPE=$(cat identifier/type.txt)
    - export PIPE_TYPE="B"

build_pipeline_A:
    stage: build
    only:
        refs:
            - master
        variables:
            - $PIPE_TYPE == "A"
    script:
        - echo $PIPE_TYPE
        - echo "Building using A."
        - mkdir "buildA"
        - touch buildA/info.txt
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - buildA/info.txt

build_pipeline_B:
    stage: build
    only:
        refs:
            - master
        variables:
            - $PIPE_TYPE == "B"
    script:
        - echo "Building using B."
        - mkdir "buildB"
        - touch buildB/info.txt
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - buildB/info.txt

test_pipeline_A:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Testing A"
        - test -f "buildA/info.txt"
    only:
        refs:
            - master
        variables:
            - $PIPE_TYPE == "A"
    dependencies:
        - build_pipeline_A

test_pipeline_B:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Testing B"
        - test -f "buildB/info.txt"
    only:
        refs:
            - master
        variables:
            - $PIPE_TYPE == "B"
    dependencies:
        - build_pipeline_B
```

Here, I have two pipelines `A` with jobs `build_pipeline_A` and `test_pipeline_A` and second pipeline as `B` with `build_pipeline_B` and `test_pipeline_B` jobs.

First I thought I can create a job `identify` which would evaluate some logic and write which pipeline to be used in a file (`identifier/type.txt`) job and update `PIPE_TYPE` variable. This variable can be used in all the jobs under `only:variables` testing and would create the job if `PIPE_TYPE` is equal to job's pipeline type, unfortunately, this didn't work.

In second try, I thought of using global `variables` and try to evaluate the expression there and set it to `PIPE_TYPE` this didn't work either.

In my last try I used a `before_script` which would evaluate the expression and set it  in `PIPE_TYPE` in hopes of `on:variables` will able to pick `PIPE_TYPE` value but no luck with this approach too.

I ran out of ideas at this point and decided to post the question.
my test's [.gitlab-ci.yaml](https://gitlab.com/daydremer/test_ci_cd/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) file, it's a public repo. so please feel free to poke around it.

Comment: The solution I came up with is

Run the `identify` stage normally and use [pipeline triggers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipeline_triggers.html) to change the `PIPE_TYPE` env. var. which would retrigger the desired pipeline.